# Observable having observable member in template

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an Angular 7 template which presents an observable `book$` having an observable `translationsAsArray$` as member:

```html
<div *ngIf="book$ | async as book">
  <dl>
    <div *ngIf="(book.translationsAsArray$ | async) as translations">
      <dt><b class="text-muted">TRANSLATIONS</b></dt>
      <dd>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li *ngFor="let translation of translations">
            <a routerLink="/books/{{translation.rid}}">{{translation.title}}</a> ({{translation.languageAsString}})
          </li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
    </div>
  </dl>
</div>
```

**Edit:** The `book.translationsAsArray$` looks as follows (just for test purposes):

```js
get translationsAsArray$(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return timer(50).pipe(
        tap(time => console.log('translationsAsArray$() subsribed')),
        map(time => [new Book(this.bookService, 'abc')]));
}
```

The problem I have is that the `translationsAsArray$` is being repeatedly re-subscribed.

When I change the solution to invoking `subscribe` in the component typescript instead of using the `async` pipe for both `book$` and `translationsAsArray$` the problem is solved.

Do you know the reason? Should my template look differently?

Comment: Could you post the code showing where `translationsAsArray$` and `term` are defined?

Comment: @AlexK: I have added the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One trick to prevent this happening is to create a template variable object with all the observables as properties, and using that to control the template:

```
<div *ngIf="{ book: (book$ | async), translations: (term.translationsAsArray$ | async) } as asyncs"
  <div *ngIf="asyncs.book">
    <dl>
      <div *ngIf="asyncs.translations">
        <dt><b class="text-muted">TRANSLATIONS</b></dt>
        <dd>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li *ngFor="let translation of asyncs.translations">
              <a routerLink="/books/{{translation.rid}}">{{translation.title}}</a> ({{translation.languageAsString}})
            </li>
          </ul>
        </dd>
      </div>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed I made a typo (now corrected) when moving the code from the source to the post. So actually `term.translationsAsArray$` should be replaced by `book.translationsAsArray$`.

Answer (score 0):

Your getter method `get translationsAsArray$()` returns a new Observable object each time it's invoked. Angular's `async` pipe sees a new object reference, so it subscribes to the new observable.

```
get observableObj() {
  // Returns a new object each time
  return timer(50);
}

constructor() {
  console.log('Testing Observable reference equality');
  const obj1 = this.observableObj;
  const obj2 = this.observableObj;
  console.log('Different Object references?', obj1 !== obj2); // true
}
```

You need to make sure your Observable object reference stays the same.

To do this, change the getter to be a regular object property:

```
book.translationsAsArray$ = timer(50).pipe(
  tap(time => console.log('translationsAsArray subscribed')),
  map(time => ['abc'])
)
```

If `translationsAsArray$` *must* be a getter, you should cache the return object so that you don't return a new object reference each time.

[StackBlitz Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vl42ek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)